# Counting elements having a given cycle structure in maximal subgroups of a generalized symmetric group

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, permutation-groups

Let $G$ be the wreath product $C_7\wr S_{18}$, where $C_7$ is the cyclic group of order 7 and $S_{18}$ is the symmetric group on 18 symbols. Consider $G$ to be embedded in the group $S_{126}=S_{7\cdot 18}$ as the centralizer of a product of 18 disjoint 7-cycles. I would like to know, for every maximal subgroup $M<G$, and for each of the cycle types $(2,63), (2,7)$, and $(7,1)$, how many elements of those cycle types are contained in $M$. By cycle type $(m,n)$ I mean a product of $n$ disjoint $m$-cycles. How can these elements be counted?

Comment: This seems too general to allow a useful answer. You could find the conjugacy classes of $H$ and then just check which representatives had the required cycle type.

Comment: Fore most cycle types, the answer is "0".

Comment: As @DerekHolt says, this question is too general. However there are lots of results about cycle type if you are willing to impose some conditions on your subgroup, for instance $k$-transitivity for some $k\geq 2$.

Comment: One specific case I'm interested in is where $H$ is a subgroup of the generalized symmetric group $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)\wr S_r$, considered as a subgroup of $S_{nr}$. I'd like to know what the possible cycle types in $H$ are, and how many elements of given cycle type there are in $H$. Unfortunately, I can only compute the conjugacy classes of $H$ if $n$ and $r$ are quite small.

Comment: A nice example of the sort of result I was talking about in my earlier comment is here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.5169.pdf The only required condition is primitivity.

Comment: Perhaps you should list a selection of the specific cases that you are interested in. The one you give should be fairly easily resolved I think -- note that calculating the cycle types that occur in $H$ is MUCH easier than calculating the conjugacy classes of $H$.

Comment: Here is the first specific case I've been unable to answer. For each maximal subgroup $M<(\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z)\wr S_{18}$, how many elements of cycle type $(2,63)$ (a product of 63 disjoint 2-cycles) does $M$ have? Similarly for the types $(2,7)$ and $(7,1)$.

Comment: To start with, you need to list maximal subgroups of $C_7\wr S_18$ up to conjugacy. Have you done this part? or is it part of the question?

Comment: Magma finds the maximal subgroups easily - there are $16$ conjugacy classes. I don't have time to think about this today, but dealing with the classes of type $(2,63)$ and $(2,7)$ should be straightfoward.

Comment: Yes, I can compute the maximal subgroups, but they seem to be too large for their conjugacy classes to be computed. I would appreciate any suggestions on how else to count these elements of given cycle type.

Comment: Let $M$ be a maximal subgroup and $K$ its intersection with the base group of the wreath product. For elements of order coprime to $7$, you can find the classes in $M/K$, which is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{18}$, and then for a representative $g$ of each class with the desired cycle structure, you know that it has $|K:C_K(g)|$ conjuagtes in $\langle g,K \rangle$.